# SwiftUI/UIKit How to convert SwiftUI Font to UIKit UIFont?

Tags: swiftui

Due to some limitations in SwiftUI Text. I've to use the UIText instead.

In an UIViewRepresentable,

```swift
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let vw = UITextView()
        let env = context.environment
        
        // UIFont?     Font?
        vw.font = env.font

        ...
    }
```

I want to initialize the UIKit UILabel using the SwiftUI EnvironmentValues.

More specifically, assign an SwiftUI Font to UIKit UIFont.

The question is, how to convert a Font to UIFont?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you need share same font, then use `UIFont` as model property and convert in SwiftUI where needed as, for example

```
Text("Some text")
   .font(Font(uiFont as CTFont))
```

Comment: I think this is a valid solution, though, if we go this route, all SwiftUI EnvironmentValues that related to Font should be manually overridden. So that both the SwiftUI and UIKit part using the unified UIFont.

Comment: It's bit off-topic, would you think there is a way that using "attributed text" or something alike in SwiftUI without go though UIKit/Appkit?

Comment: If *attributed text* is not very complex then consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/59531328/12299030

Comment: without UIKit, if we go the `Text + Text` route, we'll need a builder that parse the attributed text and built it into `Text.someModifers + Text...`. Maybe for the moment UIKit is the best choice :-).

Comment: @Asperi The solution works on paper, but in this case `Font` stops being scalable for content size categories, even if I pass the dynamic `.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)` as an initial `UIFont`. Any suggestions for this usecase?

Comment: This isn't really a solution to the question as asked - it's a concession to the shortcomings of SwiftUI. Good work-around, though.

Answer (score -2):

Create extension:

```
extension Font {
  init(_ uiFont: UIFont) {
    self = Font(uiFont as CTFont)
  }
}
```

Use as follows:

```
Text("Some text")
   .font(Font(yourUIFont))
```

Comment: They meant the other way around. How do you turn a `Font` into a `UIFont`?