# How can I get size and name from SwiftUI Font?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have fonts defined with custom parameters:

```swift
public var suiFont: Font {
    .custom(name, size: size)
}
```

And then I need to use them to create `UIKit`'s `UIFont`. How can I get parameters from `Font` struct?
I found solution for standard fonts:

```
UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).pointSize
UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).fontName
UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).fontDescriptor
```

but it's not suitable in my case because of my fonts was created with custom arguments.
For example `Font.custom("SFUI", size: 25)` returns size 17.

Are there other ways to get font parameters from SwiftUI Font?
How standard SwiftUI elements do it with wrapped UIKit elements?

Comment: It is better to keep UIFont as model and use it wrapped in Font where needed as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64369325/12299030.

Comment: Why you need to get size and name, use case?

Comment: @swiftPunk, I have `UIViewRepresentable` wrapper that needs UIFont with name and size. While fonts are SwiftUI `Font` constants.