# How to make UILabel font size static (disregard of iOS setting font size change)?

Tags: ios, swift, font-size, dynamic-type-feature

How to make UILabel font size static (disregard of iOS setting font size change)?

That is to say, when user set their font size to be larger in their iPhone's accessibility font size, or change the view to Zoomed In size, how do I keep the UILabel font size to be static and not changing because of settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found more comprehensive answers in this post:

[Fixing the size of a custom font in SwiftUI iOS 13+ when ignoring Dynamic Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956323/fixing-the-size-of-a-custom-font-in-swiftui-ios-13-when-ignoring-dynamic-type)

As well as this nice article wrote in 2021:

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/restricting-dynamic-type-sizes