# UIImageView intrinsic content size behavior with Dynamic Type

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiaccessibility, sf-symbols, dynamic-type-feature

I have an image view with its image set with a custom image (svg file with Preserve Vector Data selected). The image view has no constraint and it is told to adjust image size with accessibility.

When I run the app and change the Dynamic Type of the app in the Environment Overrides button in the Xcode Debug Area, I see the following behavior :

1. For **Dynamic Types that are below Accessibility 1** (not included) : the image view remains with a size of 24x24 (its intrinsic content size).
2. For **Dynamic Types that are above Accessibility 1** (included) : the image view gets bigger at each Dynamic Type increment.

What is weird is that if I use a SFSymbol instead of a custom image in the image view's image, the behavior for `1.` is not the same : the image view has a different intrinsic content size for each Dynamic Type increment (wether it is above or below Accessibility 1).

**- Why is that ?**

**- How can make my custom image view behave like the one with the SFSymbol ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that ?

The `Dynamic Type` feature automatically handles the image size **only when dealing with accessibility**.
This point is highlighted through the Xcode `Interface Builder` for instance: 
[image]

> How can make my custom image view behave like the one with the SFSymbol ?

As stated in your question, your '*image view has no constraint and it is told to adjust image size with accessibility.*'
If you're willing to manage this adjustement for all the possible sizes (including those lower than the a11y's), you should take a look at the following steps:

- First, be informed of a `Dynamic Type` size modification through the [**traitCollectionDidChange**](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/2020/020/#text-readibility) (see the notification section).
- Then, take into account only the sizes that aren't a11y with the [**preferredContentSizeCategory**](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/2017/245/#preferredcontentsizecategory-1523) method.
- Finally, automatically adapt the image size with an appropriate reference through the [**scaledValue**](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/2017/245/#scaled-values-1256) method.

And for the record, you may also [limit the minimum and maximum sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70246413/3825084) since iOS 15 if need be.

I suggest to take a look at this [Keith Harrison's article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/the-@scaledmetric-property-wrapper/) that covers both UIKit and SwiftUI (easiest implementation) for an example that can be easily adapted to your image size.